# React Native CLI - How to properly manage the bottom Android navigation bar color? White in light mode / Dark in dark mode?

Tags: android, react-native

Here's an image of what I'm referring to, the android emulator is on the left. I can switch my app between light / dark and the components change color on demand but I'm not sure how to approach this bottom navigation bar. Thank you in advance for any tips on this.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was a lot easier than I thought. If you're using React Navigation you can use the screen options prop to define the navigation bar color. Here is an example:

```
export function AuthStackNavigator() {
  const isDarkMode = useColorScheme() === 'dark';
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{ navigationBarColor: isDarkMode ? theme.colors.black : theme.colors.white }}>
      <Stack.Screen name="Landing" component={LandingScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```