How to change the color of the bottom bar (below the navigation tabs) in React Native

On Android, I would like to change the bottom bar on the screen from black to translucent, please check the image it's the bar below the navigation tabs. I'm developing the app with react native, using react navigation..

For me this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73674312/react-native-cli-how-to-properly-manage-the-bottom-android-navigation-bar-colo
was the fix to get it working like i want it to :-)

You can use SafeAreaView and you can add a background color for example:-
import {SafeAreaView} from 'react-native';

const Demo = ({
    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={{backgroundColor: 'black'}}>
        </SafeAreaView>
    )
})


It doesn't seem to be working

you can try this method also...
<Tab.Navigator
      tabBarOptions={{
        tabBarStyle: { backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)' }, // Translucent black color
      }}
    >
      {/* Define your tab screens here */}
</Tab.Navigator>



On modern Android devices that use gesture navigation instead of the
traditional navigation buttons you cannot change its color directly
from React Native because it is controlled by the system UI
To change the color of the navigation bar, you can use the
react-native-navigation-bar-color package

npm install react-native-navigation-bar-color
or
yarn add react-native-navigation-bar-color

below is the code
import changeNavigationBarColor from 'react-native-navigation-bar-color';

changeNavigationBarColor('green', true);


you can update your stack option styles:
      screenOptions={{ navigationBarColor: 'white' }}> // update color


Expo SDK 52, Expo router v4
In your main layout in Stack component add to a screenOptions prop:
navigationBarColor: colorScheme === "dark" ? Colors["dark"].background : Colors["light"].background
What I noticed it only works for Android. In addition if you want to change Status Bar background color, there is a code related to this in code below. You can use StatusBar component or add prop: statusBarBackgroundColor to Stack.
_layout.tsx
// (...)
import { Stack } from "expo-router";
export default function RootLayout() {
  const colorScheme = useColorScheme();

  const [loaded, error] = useFonts({
    SpaceMono: require("../assets/fonts/SpaceMono-Regular.ttf"),
    Lobster: require("../assets/fonts/Lobster-Regular.ttf"),
  });

  // Expo Router uses Error Boundaries to catch errors in the navigation tree.
  useEffect(() => {
    if (error) throw error;
  }, [error]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (loaded) {
      SplashScreen.hideAsync();
    }
  }, [loaded]);

  if (!loaded) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      <SafeAreaProvider>
        <GestureHandlerRootView>
          <Material3ThemeProvider>
            <ThemeProvider
              value={colorScheme === "dark" ? DarkTheme : DefaultTheme}
            >
              <StatusBar
                style={colorScheme === "dark" ? "light" : "dark"}
                backgroundColor={
                  colorScheme === "dark"
                    ? Colors["dark"].background
                    : Colors["light"].background
                }
              />
              <Stack
                screenOptions={{
                  navigationBarColor:
                    colorScheme === "dark"
                      ? Colors["dark"].background
                      : Colors["light"].background,
                }}
              >
                <Stack.Screen
                  name="(auth)/(tabs)"
                  options={{ headerShown: false }}
                />
                <Stack.Screen
                  name="(auth)/listing/[id]"
                  options={{
                    headerTitle: "",
                    headerBackButtonDisplayMode: "minimal",
                    headerTransparent: true,
                  }}
                />
                <Stack.Screen
                  name="(public)/login"
                  options={{
                    headerShown: true,
                    title: "Login",
                  }}
                />
                <Stack.Screen name="+not-found" />
              </Stack>
              <Toasts />
            </ThemeProvider>
          </Material3ThemeProvider>
        </GestureHandlerRootView>
      </SafeAreaProvider>
    </QueryClientProvider>
  );
}


To change the color of the bottom bar (often referred to as the bottom tab bar) below the navigation tabs in React Native, you typically need to customize the styles of the navigation component you are using. If you're using React Navigation, which is a popular navigation library for React Native, you can achieve this by customizing the styles of the tabBar component.
Here's how you can do it:
Define your custom tab bar style: You need to create a style object defining the styles for your tab bar.
Apply the custom style to your tab navigator: Pass the custom style object to the tabBarOptions prop of your tab navigator.
In this example, the tabBarStyle object defines the background color of the tab bar as blue. You can replace 'blue' with any color value you prefer.
Make sure to replace Screen1 and Screen2 with your actual screen components.
Remember to install the necessary packages (@react-navigation/native, @react-navigation/bottom-tabs) if you haven't already done so.
